# Download python from command prompt on windows

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I am connected to a machine running Windows 8 from my linux machine using OpenSSH. I need to download python3 on the Windows machine but I only have access to the command prompt, not PowerShell. I also have sftp set up, but all the python downloads are installers which don't work through the command prompt. Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: The python installer can be used from the command line https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking how to download a Python installer or run it afterwards (from the command line). Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @tdelaney yea I tried that and ran the command `python-3.8.3-amd64.e
xe /passive InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 ` and there was no output and python was still not a recognized command

Comment: Its directory may not have been added to your path. Did you try an absolute path to python.exe?

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Comment: `winget python3` or similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download using the `curl` program, if it's installed on your windows machine. Something like:

```
curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/python-3.8.3-amd64.exe -o python_install.exe
```

(or look for the Python version you want at https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Then, you can run:

```
python_install.exe /quiet
```

There are also **zip** file packages you can download from the URL above.

Note that a quiet install may not change your system's `PATH`, so you may need to locate the directory in which Python was installed, and call the program from there.

Comment: I tried that but there was no output and typing `python` into the command prompt still resulted in it not being recognized

Comment: This is probably because the `PATH` environment variable was not updated, and you need to find where Python was installed. I would guess `"c:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"`.